# "the starting is good" or "the start is good"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to give my impression about the prologue, which one 'the starting is good' or 'the start is good' is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing between both options, the better answer would be *"the start is good."*

This is because you're talking about an object, the prologue, and not an action. However, *"the start is good,"* sounds a little unnatural and isn't used by very many native English speakers.

Instead, I'd recommend something along the lines of, *"the beginning is good,"* or instead of using words like start or beginning, you have the option of mentioning the prologue as-is (e.g. *"the prologue is good."*), unless you're talking about just a section of the prologue.

Comment: Good points. Also, if you want to say that the prologue makes you want to read the rest of the story, one could also say something like, “It starts off good,” or, “It’s a promising start.”

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more likely to say

> the **first part** is good (but then it goes downhill)

"Starting" is not idiomatic.  "Starting" actually means "the *process* of beginning something" and not "the beginning *part* of [something]"

> **Starting** a new job is always exciting, but can be challenging.

As J.R. points out in his comment, you can say:

> It **starts off** good (but then gets boring).